# intersection in hours/mins of two timestamps

Tags: php

How can one achieve the intersection in hours/min between two timestamps?

```
t1 = 1970-01-01 23:00:00
t2 = 1970-01-02 11:00:00

d1 = 1970-01-01 22:30:00
d2 = 1970-01-02 01:00:00

intersection = 2h:00mins
```

a different example would be:

```
t1 = 1970-01-01 23:00:00
t2 = 1970-01-02 11:00:00

d1 = 1970-01-01 08:00:00
d2 = 1970-01-01 11:30:00

intersection = 3hrs:00minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two [DateTime](http://php.net/DateTime) objects to represent your two dates. Then, you can use the [diff](http://php.net/DateTime.diff) method to produce a [DateInterval](http://php.net/DateInterval) object, which in turn has the data you want.

Comment: Given PHP > 5.3 this is the way to go.

Comment: but i'm not looking for interval... im looking for interval only within the defined period... the intersection.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... DateInterval can tell you how many hours/minutes/whatever is between two dates. Is this not what you want? Your examples were slightly confusing, can you make them more clear?

Comment: Well i'm not sure how to make it simpler.... im not looking for just the time interval between two dates.  I'm looking for the time interval between two dates that intersects a period... (Ex1 - I'm looking to calculate those 2 hours that fall within the period of t1-t2)

Comment: Oh now I understand... In that case, you just need to check if the times fall outside the period, and if they do, adjust them to either the min or max, depending whether they are before or after the period. Then you can just use DateInterval as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have PHP > 5.3, something like the following is needed. It's not pretty, but if you want hours and minutes you could subtract the two timestamps and divide out the difference. `$past` is a flag if you want to say something like `2h:00m ago`

```
$difference = strtotime($d1) - strtotime($d2);
$past = $difference < 0;
$difference = abs($difference);
$interval_hours = (int)($difference / 3600);
$interval_minutes = (int)(($difference % 3600) / 60);
```